# Sampling from Elements except Current One

Tags: r, random

Suppose there are three possible values:  `B` ,  `S` , and  `N` . Currently there are  `10`  values in a vector called  `test` :

```
test <- c("B", "B", "S", "S", "B", "S", "S", "S", "S", "B")
```

What is a good way of getting a sample from test excluding the first element? Or excluding the second element, etc.? For example,  `sample(test,3)`  gives a sample of size  `3`  from test. But what if I want a sample of size 3 from  but not including the first element?

Comment: how about `sample(test[-1],3)`

Comment: some kind of loop `sapply(1:4, function(x) sample((1:4)[-x], 3))`

Answer (score 2):

Use `[]` to subset an object in R. To exclude, for example, the first element use `object[-1]`.

```
test
[1] "B" "B" "S" "S" "B" "S" "S" "S" "S" "B"

test[-1]
[1] "B" "S" "S" "B" "S" "S" "S" "S" "B"

set.seed(100)
sample(test[-1],3)
[1] "S" "B" "B"
```

To exclude the 3rd use, `test[-3]` and in general, to exclude the n-th, use `test[-n]`.